# Route53 configuration for subdomains for different environments in 123 reg

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have a main lets call it `example.com`. In aws I have created a hosted zone via pipeline for `test.example.com` and added its 4 NS records to domain in 123-reg.com and its working perfectly.

Now I am trying to create a stag environment `stag.example.com` and my pipeline created a new hosted zone for stag.example.com and asking to add another different 4 ns records, my question is 123-reg only allows maximum 4 ns records and if i remove the old 4 ns records my test.exmaple.com wont work anymore.
how to configure this properly?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create a set of NS records for `test.example.com` and `stage.example.com`. It sounds like you set the NS records for `example.com`, using the `test.example.com` records provided in Route53.

What I typically do is create a Route53 domain for the TLD (`example.com`), and use Route53 for the rest. That allows you to put the NS records for `example.com` into 123-reg, in your case, but manage the sub domains in Route53.